# DRF name undefined in custom serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework, serialization

When I try to hit my `api/atoms/` endpoint in the browser, I am getting a name undefined error in the views.py file, but it has a base name in urls.

Note: this is a non-model serializer and a ViewSet.

**error**

```
...views.py", line 74, in list
    instance = atom.values(), many=True)
NameError: name 'atoms' is not defined
```

**views.py**

```
class AtomViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = AtomSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = AtomSerializer(
            instance = atoms.values(), many=True) #<-------------
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
# for viewsets in views.py
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'snippets', views.SnippetViewSet)
router.register(r'atoms', views.AtomViewSet, base_name='atoms')


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.api_root),
    path('', include(router.urls)),

]
```

**serializer.py**

```
class AtomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    uid = UniqueIdProperty()
    created_at = DateTimeProperty()
    updated_at = DateTimeProperty()

    charge = IntegerProperty()
    mass = FloatProperty()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Atom(id=None, **validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for field, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, field, value)
        return instance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic python [**`NameError`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NameError) exception raised when a local or global name is not found.
The variable ***`atoms`*** is not defined in the ***`list()`*** method or globally, that's why the python interpreter raised the exception.
In your code, you'd write `atoms.values()`, which forces me to think that you are dealing with a QuerySet, which might be an **`Atom`** model.

```
class AtomViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = AtomSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = AtomSerializer(instance=Atom.objects.all(), many=True) 
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

> Note: this is a non-model serializer and a ViewSet.

You are doing **`create`** and **`update`** operations in your **`AtomSerializer`** class, and those are directly connected to the ***model***. I don't see any particular reason that pulls you back from using a ***`ModelSerializer`*** here.
 Apart from that, you are using the ***routers***, which become a good choice when you deal with the ***CRUD*** operations, hence I strongly suggest you use the combination of **`ModelViewset`** and **`ModelSerializer`** in your code.

Comment: Using a library for a graph database that doesn't use a regular model class

Comment: If your logic working, go on with it. What about my answer? Did it solve your concern?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now I understand that the view is passing data back and forth from the serializer and is still responsible for serving up the data

Answer (score 1):

In your `views.py` you did not define `atom`, you need to define it first before using it or else you will get that error.

```py
class AtomViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = AtomSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        # You need to define the atom first before passing it to your AtomSerializer
        atoms = [] # or atom = Atom.objects.all()

        serializer = AtomSerializer(
            data=atoms, 
            many=True
        )
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: "AssertionError: When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation."